# Appending to list of lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to make a list of lists in python. I am initializing this list like:

```
n = 3
adj = [[]]*n
```

So now when I `print adj`, I get:

```
[[], [], []]
```

...which is fine.

Now, I want to append values to a particular list (one particular index). I have done this:

```
adj[0].append(1)
```

Hence, my expected output is:

```
[[1], [], []]
```

However the output is:

```
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

I can't seem to understand why this is so. Probably I am not understanding something about how Python's lists work, or am making an utterly silly mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I would really appreciate a suggestion as to how I can get my desired output.

[Ideone link here.](https://ideone.com/Wm5qI4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is expected in Python. Using the * operator in this context creates *references* to the `list()` objects, which means that when you modify one such object (like you did with your `append()` operation), you modify all of the *references* to that object.

To get your desired output, I would recommend using a loop to create lists that aren't aliases of each other:

```
>>> adj = [[] for i in range(3)]
>>> adj[0].append(1)
>>> [[1], [], []]
```

Comment: wow, I had no idea. Thank you so much for the explanation. Can you please suggest a workaround?

Comment: this is a duplicate, asked a thousand times here. Check the link (use list comprehension instead)